# Getting 404 error in Next.js 14 app when i try to render my file manually and by <Link>

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js14

I can't access todolist.js. Im a beginner so I am pretty sure that there is something wrong on my side.
[code and directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wHVH.png)

If i manually type localhost:3000/todolist I still get GET http://localhost:3000/todolist 404 (Not Found). I want todolist to render and I don't know what's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a folder `todolist` and add `page.js`.

`app/todolist/page.js`

Read more on the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#pages)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand how this works, but now it's clear thanks to you.